# Chase closed my account

Tags: personal-check

My dad was in hospital sick, he wrote me a check to pay his bills for him. I deposited  the day of his death, I talked with his credit union and they approved  it and released it to my bank. Chase closed my accounts, it has been 4 weeks an I still don't have my money.

They have turned it over to loss prevention, first I was told it was being sent out. Now they say they have been trying to contact the person who wrote the check.  I told them he passed away. They still have not released it. Check was only for $1000.00 plus my money is in the account also. They won't release it either.

Comment: I'm sorry for your loss. You state that your account was closed and turned over to loss prevention? Something was very amiss way before you deposited that check. If you had outstanding debt in those accounts then it is possible that Chase is using the $1,000 to settle your debts. I recommend reading https://www.sapling.com/8460143/checking-account-given-loss-prevention

Answer (score 3):

The bank is expected to issue you a check for the balance of your account, make sure your name and address on file is correct as that is who they will make the check to and send it.

Have the credit union also contact Chase, or get a statement from the credit union, about their customer.

If the check does bounce back to the credit union and the account was under his name, then you will have to deal with the state and his estate and you will have to find a different solution for the bills.